# How to generate a sitemap.xml file in a Blazor WASM app

Tags: blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I am currently using a Blazor WASM application to host a website and a blog. Adding Google Tag Manager was not a problem but what has been puzzling me is how to add a sitemap.xml that can be dynamically generated. Has anyone had any experience in doing this?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @PaulMeems I am sorry, the company I was working for abandoned Blazor WASM and went with ReactJS instead.

Comment: its not blazor job, its backend or server (controller) job.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for this. Add **sitemap.xml** in the Blazor WebAssembly project's **wwwroot** folder.

Sample **sitemap.xml** code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
  <url>
    <loc>https://demos.getblazorbootstrap.com</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.9</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Refer to sitemap.org for more info on the sitemap.xml structure.